# Python library for visualization of RDF graph

Tags: library, python, data-visualization, rdf

Could someone point me to a Python package that can be used to visualize an RDF graph made with rdflib?

Something that for example allows me to do something similar to this pseudocode `graph.show()` which would then display the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ontospy is a good choice for you, here is the [wiki link](https://github.com/lambdamusic/OntoSpy/wiki). 
You can see some examples [here](https://github.com/lambdamusic/Ontodocs).

Comment: Could you expand a bit here as to why it is a good choice.